# php get google map pano_id using latitude and longitude in xml file

Tags: php, xml, google-maps

I want to get street view pano_id using latitude and longitude. I met to get that from this link.
http://cbk0.google.com/cbk?output=xml&ll=40.714103,-74.006206

It returns xml output and I want to get that pano_id from it. If can get A,B and C all pano_ids really appreciate that.

```
<panorama>
  <data_properties image_width="13312" image_height="6656" tile_width="512" tile_height="512" image_date="2012-08" pano_id="dIT1qZK8wyNVROwryyiN8g" imagery_type="1" num_zoom_levels="3" lat="40.714131" lng="-74.006188" original_lat="40.714096" original_lng="-74.006246" elevation_wgs84_m="-19.853310" best_view_direction_deg="120">
    <copyright>© 2013 Google</copyright>
    <text>Chambers Street</text>
    <street_range>66</street_range>
    <region>New York</region>
    <country>United States</country>
  </data_properties>
  <projection_properties projection_type="spherical" pano_yaw_deg="130.9" tilt_yaw_deg="-82.94" tilt_pitch_deg="1.15"/>
  <annotation_properties>
    <link yaw_deg="123.44" pano_id="l-oSyXcA8I9emj2IVGslvw" road_argb="0x80fffa73" scene="0">
      <link_text>Chambers Street</link_text>
    </link>
    <link yaw_deg="302.91" pano_id="TKBUYV2jeHoA7HTwX5bx7A" road_argb="0x80fffa73" scene="0">
      <link_text>Broadway / Chambers Street</link_text>
    </link>
  </annotation_properties>
</panorama>
```

[image]

Comment: For generic problems, please use the search first and take a look into the FAQ, each Tag has one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use PHP's [`SimpleXML`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php).

```
<?php

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents('http://cbk0.google.com/cbk?output=xml&ll=40.714103,-74.006206'));

foreach ($xml->data_properties as $element) {
    echo $element->attributes()->pano_id . "<br/>";
}

foreach ($xml->annotation_properties->link as $element) {
    echo $element->attributes()->pano_id . "<br/>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot friend. It worked well. Perfect !

Comment: @SumithHarshan If the answer fixed your issue, please accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer).

Comment: I already accepted ...